# Объясните принцип выполнения кода (дженерики)

Tags: java, generics

Почему в данном коде вызовется именно метод  `<T> void m(List<String> list)` ?

```
public class Ex1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> integerList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
        Gen gen = new Gen();
        gen.m(integerList);
    }

    static class Gen<T> {
        <T> void m(Collection<T> collection) {
            for (T s : collection) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }

        <T> void m(List<String> list) {
            for (String s : list) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Скорее всего он предназначен для работы конкретнотной реализацией List.

Comment: @ILYAYARATS мне кажется что во время компиляции компилятор не видит конкретного типа String (получается что-то вроде void m(List<Object> list), далее уже подставляется конкретная реализация в данном случае Integer, но ожидался String поэтому в данном случае должен возникнуть ексепшн о не возможности скастовать типы

Comment: @Санаев на самом деле все несколько сложнее. Компилятор как раз все видит и для него там List<String>. Но Java использует позднее связывание (за исключением нескольких случаев). Это значит, что метод, который нужно вызвать определяется в рантайме. И вот как раз в рантайме информация о типе generic класса стирается.

Answer (score 1):

Так как generic класс `Gen` объявлен как `raw type`, т.е. не указан никакой generic параметр при объявлении, то и методы в `Gen` будут с `raw type` параметрами, потому что эти методы члены класса, т.е. они будут просто принимать `Collection` и `List`. Тут и выбирается более подходящий метод с `List`. А сам `ClassCastException` происходит в цикле, когда объект `Integer` пытаются привести к `String`. Если `String` в цикле заменить на `Object`, то будет вызываться метод `toString` и падения не будет. Не используйте generic типы без generic параметра, у них отсутствует проверка типов во время компиляции. Используйте хотя бы `<?>` при объявлении инстанса generic класса. `Gen<?> gen = new Gen<>();`

Comment: а чем Gen<T> отличается от Gen<?>?))))

Comment: @Санаев при объявлении инстанса, а не класса `Gen<?>  gen = new Gen<>()`

Comment: так у автора в методе void m(List<String> list) , вообще не используется обобщенный дженерик, так ваш инстанс ничего не даст

Comment: @Санаев даст, выберется первый метод <T> void m(Collection<T> collection), потому что generic'и начнут работать

Comment: А это уже интересно, да действительно

Answer (score 0):

Во время компиляции компилятор не видит конкретного типа (получается что-то вроде `void m(List<Object> list)`, далее уже подставляется конкретная реализация в данном случае `Integer`, но ожидался `String` поэтому в данном случае должен возникнуть ексепшн о не возможности скастовать типы `ClassCastException`

Методы вызываются в порядке иерархии

Comment: @LittleBudda такое только в листе

Comment: @Санаев Мне не понятно, каким образом после типизации Gen<?> вызывается метод m(Collection..) если компилирование стирает все типы и мы получаем что-то вроде m(Collection<Object>...) и m(List<Object>...) ?