# Не очевидное поведение дженериков

Tags: java, generics

Есть вот такой java класс:

```java
public class SomeType<T> {

    public <E> void test(Collection<E> collection) {
        for (E e : collection) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public void test(List<Integer> list) {
        for (Integer integer : list) {
            System.out.println(integer);
        }
    }
}
```

Если исполнять код так (создать класс любым из трех вариантов):

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SomeType someType = new SomeType<>();
        //SomeType someType = new SomeType<String>();
        //SomeType someType = new SomeType();

        List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList("value");
        someType.test(stringList);
    }
```

то выбрасывается:

```java
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

И только при таком выполнении

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SomeType<String> someType = new SomeType<>();

        List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList("value");
        someType.test(stringList);
    }
```

код отрабатывает успешно и на экран выводится `value`.

Может кто-нибудь объяснить почему именно так работает java? Вроде бы дженерик тип класса `T` не связан с дженерик типом метода `E`.

И еще, если класс не дженерик:

```java
public class SomeType {

    public <E> void test(Collection<E> collection) {
        for (E e : collection) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public void test(List<Integer> list) {
        for (Integer integer : list) {
            System.out.println(integer);
        }
    }
}
```

то такой код отрабатывает нормально

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SomeType someType = new SomeType();

        List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList("value");
        someType.test(stringList);
    }
```

Comment: поправьте, в первом случае не понятно какой тип у someType, там NPE должен быть по коду

Comment: Ок, поправил. Еще два варианта оставил закоментированными.

Comment: Что то я не уверен полностью в своем ответе, удалил.

Comment: Проблема из-за того, что SomeType объявлен как raw type и всё типы у дженериков в этом классе стираются, тут подробнее: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1009317/276430 там такой же пример, только там лист с числами, а цикл со строками в методе с List, а тут лист со строками и цикл с Integer, но остальное всё так же

Answer (score 3, accepted):

в первом варианте, вы создает экземпляр `SomeType` сырого типа, параметризованные методы экземпляра сырого типа затираются и ваш метод с дженериком `Е`, после компиляции, превращается в метод вида  :

```
public Object void test(Collection collection) {
    for (Object e : collection) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

при вызове на вход метода подается `List<String>`, так как обобщенные типы инвариантны, параметр `List<String>` инвариант для `Collection`, не расширяет его, поэтому компилятор не связывает вызов с первым, дженерализированным(до компиляции) методом. 
А вот второй метод, превращается в следующее:

```
public void test(List list) {
        for (Integer integer : list) {
            System.out.println(integer);
        }
    }
```

и может принять на вход лист чего угодно, получает `List<String>` и пытается прикастовать элемент к Integer.

Для того чтобы ваш код в первом случае правильно работал вы может подать на вход такую конструкцию `Collection stringList = Arrays.asList("value");`

Comment: Если бы метод превращался в `public void test(List<?> list)`, то такой бы цикл внутри этого метода не скомпилировался бы. Он превращается тоже в сырой List `public void test(List list)`. И чтобы код правильно работал, не нужно использовать сырые типы, а объявлять дженерики хотя бы с <?>: `SomeType<?> someType =...`, `Collection<?> c = ...`