# Как дженерики влияют на связывание методов

Tags: java, generics

```
public class Ex1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> integerList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);

        Gen<?> gen = new Gen();
        gen.m(integerList);
    }

    static class Gen<T> {

        <T> void m(Collection<T> collection) {
            for (T s : collection) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }

        <T> void m(List<String> list) {
            for (String i : list) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Объяcните пожалуйста почему в этом коде будет вызван `m(Collection...)`, а не `m(List...)`

UPD.Уточню, я понимаю что дело в wildcard `Gen<?> gen`. Не понимаю каким образом он влияет на связывание. Если будет просто `Gen ge`n, то вызывается `m(List....)`

И  вот в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1009297/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8) вопросе нет ответа на мой: "*Почему типизация Gen влияет на связывание, если в рантайме (когда происходит связывание) она уже стерта.*"

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon В том вопросе так и не ответили, почему после типизации Gen<?> начинает вызываться метод m(Collection...). Ведь связывание происходит в райнтайме,а в рантайме все типы уже стерты,тогда почему типизация влияет на связывание методов?

Comment: Кроме динамического(в рантайме) есть и статическое(при компиляции) связывание, динамическое используется при наследовании и полиморфизме(переопределение методов), статическое при перегрузке. Тут перегрузка метода и статическое связывание

Comment: Да,я понял,спасибо.